# Does happen-before relationship impact priority inversion?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, happens-before, priority-inversion

I am wondering does happen-before relationship such as `volatile` variable or `finally` block to release a lock have something to do *priority inversion*? I understand that these impose a happen-before relationship that the compiler can't reorder the instruction. Does it also impact *priority inversion* at all, or are they separate concepts? Can someone give me an example to understand this better?

Comment: I think priority inversion has absolutely nothing to do with any of the other things you mentioned. Priority inversion is about scheduling tasks of different priorities, what can `volatile` and `finally` can possibly have to do with this ?

Comment: A priority inversion can involve a lock (not) being released, yes. But I'm not sure what connection you're asking about between priority inversion and memory barriers / instruction reordering. Can you clarify what you're asking? What connection do you think there might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate concepts.  "Priority inversion" is the idea that if some high-priority thread P is blocked, waiting for a lower-priority thread L to do something, then it would be advantageous for the OS to temporarily boost the priority of L to be at least as high as the priority of P.

"Happens Before" is a guarantee made in the Java Language Specification that helps us to reason about if and when memory updates made by one thread  become visible to some other thread.